# Create USRPRF in as400 other than QSYS lib

Tags: ibm-midrange

How to create user profile other that QSYS lib in AS400. Is AS400 permit users to create user profile other than QSYS lib or QSYS is default library to create user profile in AS400/IBMi.

Comment: All user profile objects are stored in QSYS.  I don't think it's possible to put them anywhere else.

Comment: All *USRPRF objects **must exist** in the QSYS library. If you explain the _business problem_ that you need to solve, we might have suggestions. So far, you're asking about an impossible _technical problem_.

Answer (score 6):

1. No, it is not possible.
2. Why would one want to do this?
3. The place to start looking for documentation is the [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i).